# CUDA example in Julia doesn't use GPU

Tags: julia, gpu

I'm doing my first steps on running Julia 1.6.5 code on GPU. For some reason, it seems the GPU is not being used at all. These are the steps:

First of all, my GPU passed on the test recommended at [CUDA Julia Docs](https://cuda.juliagpu.org/stable/):

```
# install the package
using Pkg
Pkg.add("CUDA")
  
# smoke test (this will download the CUDA toolkit)
using CUDA
CUDA.versioninfo()

using Pkg
Pkg.test("CUDA")    # takes ~40 minutes if using 1 thread
```

Secondly, the below code took around 8 minutes (real time) for supposedly running on my GPU. It loads and multiplies, for 10 times, two matrices 10000 x 10000:

```
using CUDA
using Random
N = 10000

a_d = CuArray{Float32}(undef, (N, N))
b_d = CuArray{Float32}(undef, (N, N))
c_d = CuArray{Float32}(undef, (N, N))

for i in 1:10
    global a_d = randn(N, N)
    global b_d = randn(N, N)

    global c_d = a_d * b_d
end

global a_d = nothing
global b_d = nothing
global c_d = nothing
GC.gc()
```

Outcome on terminal as follows:

```
(base) ciro@ciro-G3-3500:~/projects/julia/cuda$ time julia cuda-gpu.jl

real    8m13,016s
user    50m39,146s
sys 13m16,766s
```

Then, an equivalent code for the CPU is run. Execution time was also equivalent:

```
using Random
N = 10000

for i in 1:10
    a = randn(N, N)
    b = randn(N, N)

    c = a * b
end
```

Execution:

```
(base) ciro@ciro-G3-3500:~/projects/julia/cuda$ time julia cuda-cpu.jl

real    8m2,689s 
user    50m9,567s 
sys 13m3,738s
```

Moreover, by following the info on NVTOP screen command, it is weird to see the GPU memory and cores being loaded/unloaded accordingly, besides still using the same 800% CPUs (or eight cores) of my regular CPU, which is the same usage the CPU-version has.

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This hint brings an execution error, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of things that prevent your code from working properly and fast.

First, you are overwriting your allocated `CuArray`s with normal CPU Arrays by using `randn`, which means that the matrix multiplication runs on the CPU.
You should use `CUDA.randn` instead. By using `CUDA.randn!`, you are not allocating any memory beyond what was already allocated.

Secondly, you are using global variables and the global scope, which is bad for performance.

Thirdly, you are using `C = A * B` which reallocates memory. You should use the in-place version `mul!` instead.

I would propose the following solution:

```
using CUDA
using LinearAlgebra
N = 10000

a_d = CuArray{Float32}(undef, (N, N))
b_d = CuArray{Float32}(undef, (N, N))
c_d = CuArray{Float32}(undef, (N, N))

# wrap your code in a function
# `!` is a convention to indicate that the arguments will be modified
function randn_mul!(A, B, C)
    CUDA.randn!(A)
    CUDA.randn!(B)
    mul!(C, A, B)
end

# use CUDA.@time to time the GPU execution time and memory usage:
for i in 1:10
    CUDA.@time randn_mul!(a_d, b_d, c_d)
end
```

which runs pretty fast on my machine:

```sh
$ time julia --project=. cuda-gpu.jl
  2.392889 seconds (4.69 M CPU allocations: 263.799 MiB, 6.74% gc time) (2 GPU allocations: 1024.000 MiB, 0.05% memmgmt time)
  0.267868 seconds (59 CPU allocations: 1.672 KiB) (2 GPU allocations: 1024.000 MiB, 0.01% memmgmt time)
  0.274376 seconds (59 CPU allocations: 1.672 KiB) (2 GPU allocations: 1024.000 MiB, 0.01% memmgmt time)
  0.268574 seconds (59 CPU allocations: 1.672 KiB) (2 GPU allocations: 1024.000 MiB, 0.01% memmgmt time)
  0.274514 seconds (59 CPU allocations: 1.672 KiB) (2 GPU allocations: 1024.000 MiB, 0.01% memmgmt time)
  0.272016 seconds (59 CPU allocations: 1.672 KiB) (2 GPU allocations: 1024.000 MiB, 0.01% memmgmt time)
  0.272668 seconds (59 CPU allocations: 1.672 KiB) (2 GPU allocations: 1024.000 MiB, 0.01% memmgmt time)
  0.273441 seconds (59 CPU allocations: 1.672 KiB) (2 GPU allocations: 1024.000 MiB, 0.01% memmgmt time)
  0.274318 seconds (59 CPU allocations: 1.672 KiB) (2 GPU allocations: 1024.000 MiB, 0.01% memmgmt time)
  0.272389 seconds (60 CPU allocations: 2.000 KiB) (2 GPU allocations: 1024.000 MiB, 0.00% memmgmt time)

real    0m8.726s
user    0m6.030s
sys     0m0.554s
```

Note that the first time the function was called, the execution time and memory usage was higher because you are measuring compilation time any time a function is first called with a given type signature.

Answer (score 1):

After playing a little bit, the following code also works. Interesting to note the declaration "global" on c_d variable. Without it, the system complained about ambiguity between the (global) CuArray c_d and the assumption of a different (unintended local) variable c_d.

```
using CUDA
using Random
N = 10000

a_d = CuArray{Float32}(undef, (N, N))
b_d = CuArray{Float32}(undef, (N, N))
c_d = CuArray{Float32}(undef, (N, N))

for i in 1:10
    randn!(a_d)
    randn!(b_d)

    global c_d = a_d * b_d
end

global a_d = nothing
global b_d = nothing
global c_d = nothing
GC.gc()
```

The outcome on a relatively modest GPU confirms the result:

```
(base) ciro@ciro-Inspiron-7460:~/projects/julia/cuda$ time julia cuda-gpu.jl

real    0m38,243s
user    0m36,810s
sys 0m1,413s
```